# why doesn't DATE_FORMAT seem toa

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, null

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('%m-%e-%Y','2010-01-05');
```

Why is it that that returns NULL when I'd expect it to return 05-01-2010? The sql fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db6d96/1

Thanks!

Comment: What month is month 2010?  The format is incorrect for the layout.  Try `'%Y-%m-%d'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrongly.

[DATE_FORMAT(date,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

First param is date and 2nd param is format as

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT('2010-01-05','%m-%e-%Y');
```

AND if the input date is in the format Y-m-d ( which is mysql date format)

Then to convert it to d-m-Y it should be

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT('2010-01-05','%d-%m-%Y');
```